# Can someone help me understand $\lim \sup$ and $\lim \inf$.

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, limsup-and-liminf

I am reviewing for a final exam and it seems as though I am still not understanding $\limsup$, $\liminf$, $\min$ and $\max$. I wanted to check my understanding here if you don’t mind. Basically, I have a 2 part question.

1. If I understand this correctly, $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ are basically found by taking an arbitrary sub sequence and analyzing it as the index goes to infinity, yes? With that said, if it is bounded (containing brackets) then clears contain the $\liminf$ and sup respectively, yes? Moreover, I know the $\min$ and $\max$ are the lowest and highest values in the set, but how come they sometimes don’t exist?
2. Here is a sample problem I am reviewing:

$X=\left\lbrace x\in[0,1] | x \text{ is irrational}\right\rbrace$

I know that since the set is bounded between $0$ and $1$ that my $\liminf$ is $0$ and my $\limsup$ is $1$, correct? My $\min$ and $\max$ should also be $0$ and $1$, yes?

Comment: But $0,1 \notin X$

Comment: How do we know the 0,1 is not contained in X?

Comment: They are not irrational, they are rational. So they are not in X.

Comment: Right, but why doesn’t X contain irrational numbers? If X is a continuous function shouldn’t it contain all numbers?

Comment: X has no min and max of course

Comment: X is a set, not a function

Comment: You defined $X$ as a set of only irrational numbers in the $[0,1]$ range.

Comment: @AnthonythomasGORNIAK You define $X$ to be all the **irrationals** in $[0,1],$ so of course $X$ doesn't contain $0,1.$

Comment: I see... so because it does not contain 0,1 then we have no max in and min yes?

Comment: $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ make sense for **sequences**, not for sets.

Comment: Thank you guys for assisting me. I am trying out other practice problems and I actually understand this concept.

Answer (score 4):

First of all $\sup,\ \inf,\ \max,\ \min$ are defined for sets.

$\sup A$ is a number $a$ s. t.  $\forall  \alpha \in A,\ \alpha \leq a$ AND there is no number $b$ s. t. $\forall  \alpha \in A, \alpha \leq b \leq a$. So it is the smallest number, that bounds $A$. For example $\sup (0;1) = 1$, and $\sup [0;\infty)$ doesn`t exist.

$\inf$ defined similary, but with $\geq$ instead of $\leq$.

$\max$ and $\min$ are similar but should be contained in the set. For example for $(0;1)$ neither $\min$ nor $\max$ exists, $\min [0,1) = 0$, $\max$ not exists, etc.

$\lim \sup$ has a different nature. It is defined for functions or sequences. It basically supremum as function tends to some point. And makes sense for oscillating functions for example. I.e. there is no $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow \infty}\sin x$, but $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow \infty}\sup \sin x = 1$.

So for your set $\sup, \inf$ are $0, 1$ correspondingly. $min, max$ do not exist. And $\lim \sup, \lim\inf$ make no sense.